# Python - Radio buttons and variables

Tags: tkinter

I'm using this program to select (via radio buttons) the model to be used in a project. The program would then calculate the probability of failure, accordingly.
I used this code:

```
from Tkinter import *  
menu=Tk()    
def novo(n)
failure=random.randrange(10)
 if n==1:
     n=failure+5
 if n==2:
     n=failure+10
 if n==3:
     n=failure+15
 return n    
l1=Label(menu,text=" What model to use?").pack()
r1=Radiobutton(menu,text=' model 1',value=1,command=novo(1)).pack()
r2=Radiobutton(menu,text=' model 2',value=2,command=novo(2)).pack()
r3=Radiobutton(menu,text=' model 3',value=3,command=novo(3)).pack()
l2=Label(menu,text="Probability of failure:).pack()
l3=Label(menu,textvariable=n).pack()
b1=Button(menu,text="quit",command=menu.destroy).pack()    
menu.mainloop()
```

Цhen I run the program, only the Menu window with the Radio buttons and the text "Probability of failure" appears.
Why is it not printing the result of the function novo()?

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, and you have several syntax errors. This code can't possibly be giving you the errors or behavior you say it does because it can't run at all. Please post _actual_ code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this line of code:

```
r1=Radiobutton(menu,text=' model 1',value=1,command=novo(1)).pack()
```

There are two things wrong with this code. The first problem, which is related to your problem, is that the code will call `novo` *at the time the button is created*, and whatever that function returns is given to the `command` attribute.

The `command` attribute takes a reference to a function. Instead, you are *calling* a function, and using the result. The simplest solution is to use lambda, which makes it easy to create an anonymous function. This anonymous function can then call your function with an argument:

```
r1=Radiobutton(..., command=lambda: novo(1))...
```

For a longer explanation, search tkinter questions for lambda -- this question gets asked and answered a lot.

The second problem is that `r1` (and all the other similar variables) will always be `None`.  In python, when you do something like `x=foo().bar()`, `x` will always get the result of the last function. Thus, when you do `r1=Radiobutton(...).pack(...)`, you will always get the result of `pack()`, which is always `None`.

The best practice for Tkinter is to separate the creation of the widget from the layout of the widget. In your case it doesn't matter because you never reuse these variables, but you should get in the habit of coding this way. For example:

```
r1 = Radiobutton(...)
r2 = Radiobutton(...)
r3 = Radiobutton(...)
...
r1.pack()
r2.pack()
r3.pack()
...
```

This has the advantage of making your code easier to maintain, since all of your layout code is in one place. I see lots of questions where people can't understand why their code doesn't look the way they expect, and it often boils down to the fact they have grid and/or pack statements scattered throughout their code, making it very hard to see mistakes or to visualize what the code should be doing.